# Is there any Null-Conditional Operator like for Events.. Button?.Click +=(ss,ee)

Tags: c#, .net, events, c#-7.0, null-conditional-operator

Why there's no Null-Conditional Operator for events ?

For example i have following code which raise event if object is not null :

```
Button TargetButton =  null;

    if(IsRunning)
    {
       TargetButton = new ....
    }

TargetButton?.Click +=(ss,ee)=>{...}

// Compile-time error 
// The event 'EditorButton.Click' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
```

**briefly :**

is there alternative ? than using usual `if(TargetButton != null ) ... raise event`

Why there's no null-conditional operator for event. and it accept null ?
http://prntscr.com/pv1inc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to events.

The null-conditional operator is to stop an evaluation if a reference is null.

It is not applicable in the left or right part of an assignment.

If you have:

```
public class Test
{
  public int Value;
  public void Method() { }
}
```

You can't write:

```
Test v;

v?.Value = 10;

int a = v?.Value;
```

Because if v is null, v.Value is not evaluated.

- So what to do with `= 10` ?
- Or what to do with `a` ?

Thus it is the same when adding or removing an event handler to an event variable that is null when empty.

[C# event is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742862/c-sharp-event-is-null)

Hence the compiler error to disallow such writings.

It is why you can't write:

```
TargetButton?.Click +=(ss,ee)=>{...}
```

Because what to to with `(ss,ee)=>{...}` if `TargetButton` is null?

You can say that you want the compiler ignores that.

But the compiler disallows doing such unclean thing.

What we can write is:

```
v?.Test();
```

Here is v is null the method is not called and all is fine because there is nothing right or left that the compiler does not know what to do with.

```
int a = v?.Value ?? 0;
```

Here if v is null 0 is used.

[Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

[Null-coalescing operators ?? and ??=](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: But man. if so why events accept null ? http://prntscr.com/pv1inc

Comment: If events accept null ? why Null-Conditional not working as regular properties or instances of class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742862/c-sharp-event-is-null

Comment: @devmuhammadkamal In the example in Olivier's answer, `v = null;` is also valid. What's your point?

Comment: But am still confusing ? maybe i need to learn more about events or... why null-conditional not working exactly with events ? -.-

Comment: this line : It is not applicable in the left or right part of an assignment, you mean we can't use null-conditional operator with ... ?

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks sir i got what i want :)

Comment: You can't use the null-conditional operator operator in an expression having an assignment, without the null-coalescing operator. It is a rule to protect coders from unclean practices.

Answer (score 0):

Events are little more then a Add() and Remove() accessor wrapped around a Delegate. However what can be a bit confusing is that class code can access it fully (read, nulling, etic) under the Event name.

The way to call them looks like this. I took the example from INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
//Declaring the event
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

//the function that raises the Events.
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(
//That attribute is almost unique for the function of NotifyPropertyChange
//It puts in teh propertyName if nothing is given
//You just use normal paramters here
[CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
{  
    //Nullcheck, Invoke with EventArgs containing the propertyName
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I do remember a old information you should copy the event list into a local variable. I think it was something about multitasking or Enumerator changes.

```
//volatile so Optimisations will not cut it out
volatile var localCopy = PropertyChanged
```

Comment: oh its not cute -.-, but operators will make cutie

Comment: But i talking about the already declaring events from standard .NET. that i can't modified. so i can't make Button.Click?.Invoke() will not work because event are not in same class that i worked with.

Comment: @devmuhammadkamal A select few raise functions are `protected virtual void RaisePostBackEvent (string eventArgument);` - protected and virtual, so inheritors can override them. Check if there is such a function.

Answer (score 0):

Events itself isn't null. but you can create a handler and assign it to the event.

```
EventHandler handler = myEvent;
handler?.Invoke(args);
```